# Electric field in conducting media

Tags: electromagnetism

I know that the electric field is zero inside a perfect conductor. However, I am here discussing non-perfect conductors. So let's suppose we have a conducting medium with conductivity $\sigma_1$ and electric permittivity $\epsilon_1$. Another conducting medium is enclosed by the first medium and this one has conductivity $\sigma_2$ and electric permittivity $\epsilon_2$. Now both media are subjected to an external uniform electric field. The question is what is the electric field inside the first medium and what is the electric field inside the second medium. My understanding is that a steady-current is induced that flows in both media but I'm little confused and would appreciate some help.

Comment: A conductor doesn't have to be perfect for its internal electric field to be zero. The conductivity just needs to be greater than zero. There can't be a steady current because that would dissipate energy due to resistive losses and in your setup there is no input of energy.

Comment: First, I believe the input of energy to be the external applied electric field. Second, from Ohm's law we have $\mathbf{j}=\sigma \mathbf{E}$, so an applied field in ohmic media will induce a current. In a perfect conductor $\sigma\rightarrow \infty$ and therefore for $\mathbf{j}$ to remain bounded we must have $\mathbf{E}=0$. However, I see no reason for the electric field to be zero inside a non-perfect conductor.

Comment: The total field is zero because charge migration in the conductor sets up a field that opposes and balances out the external field i.e. charge flows only until the two fields balance, then stops. This only requires the charge mobility be non-zero, not that it be infinite.